# Is life a fair test?

Tags: allah, death, theology, eschatology, divine-justice

Allah is fair to all of his slaves however this life is a test for all of us yet we all don't have the same amount of time on this test (Earth). Some people get longer time and they live to an older age and some people have less time for the same test as they die at a younger age. I understand that having more time could also mean you are at risk of getting more sins if you do not use your time wisely but equally you have more time to collect good deeds and please Allah. What if in the last few years of your old age you change and decide to leave behind your haram life style and only please Allah? What if you are a non-Muslim and decide you want to revert?

You may say because it is a test, but then what about children? Why are they brought to life on Earth if they will not really be tested because their life is taken away from them while they are a child? This means at this age they do not have any sins so will be granted Jannah.

I mean personally if I had a choice of when to be taken away, I would have chosen a time in my childhood when I was considered an innocent child or even a baby because at this time I do not have sins and so will be granted Jannah. We all will have to die one day and that is for sure so a younger age would be better than going through the pain of trails.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an extremely vital component to the question which you have proposed.

`Rahma`.

There are countless, a plethora of hadith and ayah of the Quraan which show-case the mercy of Allah.

In fact, the mercy *can* reach to an extent where a complete invalid in relation to Islamic duties can attain the highest level of Paradise.

Allah, the diety of Islam does as he pleases.

An individual who has been scrupulous in his Islamic affairs can very well reside in the hereafter in a level of Jannah that is equal to one who used to consume alcohol on a daily basis and forego his prayers regularly.

You are also over-looking another factor which are the signs, tests, trials and tribulations which Allah has put in to place for man-kind.

Everyone is tested to their capacity. The Sahaba went through hardships which are like fairy-tales in comparison to the struggle which Muslims face today.

A perfected, calculated process will be brought forward to your court case in the hereafter. A person who has not had access to water in abundance as I do will not be questioned for the usage of that water. Similarly, your deeds, good or bad will be in relation to what you had access to. There is complete justice, i.e. fairness.

Comment: So why do some babies die as babies? What is the point of them being born if they won't really be tested since this life is a test? They die without being tested and are granted Jannah but that is not the case for everyone.

Comment: @Zohal What is the point they are being born? What is the point you are born at all? What is the point some grow very old? We can go on the whole day. I think the question is not thought about deep enough. Maybe we don't know why the baby dies. What is the point? God knows. The parents might be tested. They might rethink their life. What if they now adopt a child out of fear of losing one while getting a new? And by doing that they might save that kid. That kid might turn Muslim.. And so on and so on.... We can't know. But a very little step can turn out to have a HUGE impact on the future.

Comment: @Zohal It might be a test for the parents, relatives and such. Try to think it from other angles. As for the babies, only Allah knows how will they be judged.

Comment: @SpiderRico Angels were not created to be tested as they do not have free will and so cannot go against the words of Allah but human can sin. So it's not the same thing.